# redirect to mobile detail page layout from flow

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, pagereference, redirect, visual-flows

I am creating a custom object record via a flow. At the end of the flow, the user is redirected to the detail of the record that has just been created in order to add some attachment.

Users will use the functionality via Salesforce1, so I was wondering if it was possible to redirect the user to the mobile layout of the record. I have the id and tried with the following code in my getFinishLocation() method:

```
mobileParam = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('t');
result = new PageReference('/one/one.app#/sObject/'+flowPageName.objectId+'/view?t=/'+mobileParam);
```

but it is not working from salesforce1. 
How can I redirect to the mobile detail page of the created record?

Comment: Is your detail page VF or standard page?

Comment: standard page, not vf

Comment: please redirect to normail detail view with just pagereference method pointing to Id of the record .When you test in SF1 it should redirect to the mobile View.THanks

Comment: I already tried with result = new PageReference('/'+flowName.objectId); but i dont see the mobile version from sf1

Comment: Make certain the standard page you're redirecting to is enabled for SF1.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue.